# What do I need to be able to propose multiple tag wiki edits?

Tags: support

I recently proposed a tag usage guidance edit, and it's sitting in the queue; however, when I wanted to [propose another one](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/367), I instead get redirected to the page that tells me that [All registered users may propose new tag wikis](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/measurement-devices/info), but does not allow me to make any edits.  I suspect that it's because I have an unapproved tag edit sitting in the queue.

What would I need to do, to be allowed to propose multiple tag edits?  E.g., is it a certain amount of rep?  Or is this a bug?  Does this have something to do with the fact that, noone on this site has the 4000 rep yet, necessary to edit tags without going through a queue?